# Is it possible to make the box bigger on Swagger UI?

Tags: python, flask, swagger, connexion

### Environment

- Python 3.11.6
- flask 2.2.5
- connexion 2.14.2
- swagger-ui-bundle 0.0.9 (installed by `pip install connexion[swagger]`)

### Problem

I would like to know how to make this box bigger. I checked Swagger UI website (e.g. https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/), but didn't find a good solution.

[image: Swagger UI]

### Part of code

```
parameters:
  id:
    name: "id"
    description: "Very loooooooooooooooog ID"
    in: path
    required: True
    schema:
      type: "string"
```

Comment: On the page you referenced there are items related to min/maxlength, format (UUID?) and pattern (regex to specify what can be put in the field).  Have you tried adding those options?

Comment: I tried `maxLength`, but the field doesn't affect the size of this blank box. This is not UUID, so I didn't try it.

Comment: is it that it is not allowing you to enter the full string or just not displaying it?  and did you try the Try It button to see what the box looks like then?  I have used swagger.io for another products api but have never defined it myself.   It might be possible for you to affect the CSS so that that field has a greater width on the screen.  not sure though.  might be helpful if you updated your question with more context on how to reproduce your results.  I would not be able to from your current text.